# pg_hba.conf like access control

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I`m trying to achieve separate sql access.

One subnet must be allowed to connect to `google-cloud-sql` instance without `ssl`, other one using ssl.

After editing `pg_hba.conf` using `google-cloud-console` and restarting the instance, changes are not enforced. All access configs stay the same as configured through GUI.

Is it even supported?

Answer (score 0):

Making such changes, directly to pg_hba.conf, is not supported. As you well mention, configuration from the GUI will prevail. Handling configuration files directly is not aligned to the product’s purpose as a managed service.

You can [enable SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance) connections through Cloud Console and still allow unsecured connections or enforce SSL for all connections. Unfortunately, whichever setting you choose will apply to all [authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip#add).